# Center-align shared y-axis text between plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dummy data and plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

test_data <- data.frame(sample = c("sample1_long_label","sample2","sam3","sample4_long_labels_are_annoying"),
                        var1 = c(20,24,19,21),
                        var2 = c(4000, 3890, 4020, 3760))

p1 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(var1, sample)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(var2, sample)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

p1 + p2
```

This creates a plot that looks like this:
[image]

Now, the y-axis labels are right-aligned to the right plot (they have been removed in the left plot). I would like the y-axis labels to be center-aligned between the two plots. Is this possible? If not, any other method that will create a similar plot is welcome.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the labels may be of different lengths, and have adjusted the test data. Is it possible to make the whole label visible in the center while center-adjusting the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be easiest to control the spacing through the y-axis text margin, and discard any other margins or spacing. To do this:

- Set the right margin of the left plot to 0
- Set the left margin of the right plot to 0
- Set the tick length of the right plot to 0. Even though these are blank, still space is reserved for them.
- Set the right and left margins of the axis text of the right plot.

In the code below, 5.5 points is the default margin space, but feel free to adjust that to personal taste.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

test_data <- data.frame(sample = c("sample1","sample2","sample3","sample4"),
                        var1 = c(20,24,19,21),
                        var2 = c(4000, 3890, 4020, 3760))

p1 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(var1, sample)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(5.5, 0, 5.5, 5.5))

p2 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(var2, sample)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "pt"),
        plot.margin = margin(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 0),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text(margin = margin(0, 5.5, 0, 5.5)))

p1 + p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

EDIT: To center align labels with various lengths, you can use `hjust` as per usual: `axis.text.y.left = element_text(margin = margin(0, 5.5, 0, 5.5), hjust = 0.5)`.

Answer (score 1):

A second option would be to add the axis labels via a third plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

test_data <- data.frame(sample = c("sample1","sample2","sample3","sample4"),
                        var1 = c(20,24,19,21),
                        var2 = c(4000, 3890, 4020, 3760))

p1 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(var1, sample)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(var2, sample)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())

p3 <- ggplot(test_data, aes(1, sample)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = sample)) +
  scale_x_reverse() +
  theme_void()

p1 + p3 + p2 +
  plot_layout(widths = c(4, 1, 4))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, looks promising! However, the specified width of the center plot would need to be different if the labels are of different lengths. I forgot to specify this in the question. Is there a way to auto-adjust to label length?

Comment: I'm afraid in that case you are better off with the approach by teunbrand. TBMK patchwork only allows to set relative widths while allowing for labels of different widths would require to set the width of the middle plot in absolute units. And while that should be possible in principle I would guess that this requires some (or a lot of) additional effort.